# Test a Backbone.js View

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I'm currently testing a backbone view with Jasmine and I am having some trouble. I'm trying to isolate the View from all the other elements (the other view that are instantiated, the collection), but it is nearly impossible.

```
initialize: function(options) {
    if(options.return) {return;}
    var view = this;
    var name = options.name;
    var localizedElements = app.helpers.Locale.l().modules.case[name];
    var swap, notification;
    this.name = name.capitalizeFirstLetter();
    this.collection.on('sort', this.refreshGui, this);
    return this.render('/case/' + name + '/' + this.name + 'Box.txt', localizedElements, this.$el).done(function() {
        new app.views.Buttons({el: view.$el.find('.Buttons')});
        _.each(view.collection.models, function(model) {
            new app.views['Folded' + this.name]({model: model, el: this.$('table')});
        }, view);
        if(!view.collection.findWhere({isPreferred: true}) || !view.collection.findWhere({isPrescribedForms: true})) {
            if(!view.collection.findWhere({isPreferred: true})) {
                swap = {entity: 'address', preferenceType: 'preferred'};
                notification = app.helpers.Locale.l().generic.warningMessages.missingPreference.swap(swap);
                var preferredNotification = [notification];
                app.helpers.Notification.addNotifications('warnings', {missingPreferred: preferredNotification});
            }
            if(!view.collection.findWhere({isPrescribedForms: true})) {
                swap = {entity: 'address', preferenceType: 'prescribed forms'};
                notification = app.helpers.Locale.l().generic.warningMessages.missingPreference.swap(swap);
                var prescribedFormsNotification = [notification];
                app.helpers.Notification.addNotifications('warnings', {missingPrescribedForms: prescribedFormsNotification});
            }
        }
    });
},
```

For example, where there are the two "ifs", the view is talking to the collection and a helper: "Notification Helper". How am I suppose to test this part of the code if I mocked the collection and the notification helper? I mean I am testing the VIEW, but now it seems like I have to test other elements of my application in my view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to isolate the View from all the other elements

I'm not sure if this will be helpful for you, but I created my own strategy to handle this problem.
The problem with Backbone is often indeed, that the view objects become cluttered with functionality.
Personally, I like my views to handle DOM interactions, listen to DOM events.
But to execute business logic / interactions with the back end, I prefer to delegate this functionality to other 'external' objects.

Models on the other hand 'may' handle basic data validation but do nothing more than making RESTful interactions with the server in my application.

How I solved the problem is by instantiating custom Javascript ('controller') objects that act as intermediaries between the views and the models.
This object is nothing more than an object that looks approximately like this:

```
var Some_controller = function(options){ 
    this.makeView(); 
}; 

Some_controller.prototype.makeView = function(){
    var someView = new Some_view({'controller': this}); 
    someView.render(); //Render, but can also take care of proper view cleanup to avoid zombie objects 
}; 

Some_controller.prototype.getModel = function(){ 
    var someModel = new Some_model(); 
    var promise = model.fetch(); 
    return promise; //Promise be called from the view, because the controller is passed via the options, when the view is instantiated.  
};
```

Well, this is how I try to keep my views clean.
In my experience, it is very easy to find everything back immediately; and note that you can also use helper objects to isolate more specific business functionality.
Not sure if anyone else has a better solution for this.

Comment: That's pretty awesome! Thanks.